# How to read_csv with incorrectly formatted file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a text file as sample below:

```
col A,col B,col C,col D,col E
val A1,val B1,val C1,val D1,val E1, val E2, val E3
val A2,val B2, val C2,val D2, val E4
```

Please note that some values in col E has multiple values which contains "," e.g **val E1, val E2, val E3**

When I use `df = pd.read_csv(r'path/text_file.txt',  sep="\t")`, it reads as one column instead of multiple columns as below:

| col A,col B,col C,col D,col E |
| --- |
| val A1,val B1,val C1,val D1,val E1, val E2, val E3 |
| val A2,val B2, val C2,val D2, val E4 |

The expected dataframe as below:

| col A | col B | col C | col D | col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val A1 | val B1 | val C1 | val D1 | val E1, val E2, val E3 |
| val A2 | val B2 | val C2 | val D2 | val E4 |

I tried replacing the delimiter with "," instead of "\t" but it wouldn't work since in col E, I have multiple values which is separated by ",".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This solution is **80x faster** than this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820680/7758804), on a file with 31201 rows.
- The file is not a correctly formatted csv file. Multiple comma separated values that belong in 1 column should be in double quotes like `"val E1, val E2, val E3"`.

### Repair the data format

1. `.open` the file and fix with a list comprehension
2. Iterate through each row of strings with `for l in f`
3. Split each row into a list with `row := l.strip().split(',')`, which uses an assignment expression (`:=`) and requires `python >= 3.8`

   - **An option without `:=` is at the bottom**
4. Fix the rows

   - `[','.join(row[4:])]` joins anything >= index 4 into a single string in a list, which is them combined back to the list of the first 4 values, `row[:4]`.
5. Load into the dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

with open('test.txt') as f:
    rows = [row[:4] + [','.join(row[4:])] for l in f if (row := l.strip().split(',')) is not None] 

df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])

# display(df)
    col A   col B    col C   col D                   col E
0  val A1  val B1   val C1  val D1  val E1, val E2, val E3
1  val A2  val B2   val C2  val D2                  val E4

df.to_csv('test.txt', index=False)

# properly formatted csv
col A,col B,col C,col D,col E
val A1,val B1,val C1,val D1,"val E1, val E2, val E3"
val A2,val B2, val C2,val D2, val E4
```

### `%%timeit` comparison

- Performed on `test.txt` with 31201 rows

```py
%%timeit
with open('test.txt') as f:
    rows = [row[:4] + [','.join(row[4:])] for l in f if (row := l.strip().split(',')) is not None]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])

[result]: 50.8 ms ± 3.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
df=pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None, skiprows=1, engine='python')
cols=pd.read_csv('test.txt',skipfooter=len(df)).columns
df[4]=df.loc[:,4:].agg(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()),1)
df=df.loc[:,:4]
df.columns=cols

[result]: 4.04 s ± 30 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Option without assignment expression

- `%%timeit` of `54.3 ms ± 1.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    rows = list()
    for l in f:
        row = l.strip().split(',')
        row = row[:4] + [','.join(row[4:])]
        rows.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting the file:

Firstly read your csv file without a header then get the cols name in your csv file after that join cells values of column 4: by `','` then get the df upto column 4 by using iloc and finally set the columns names and save the file to csv

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'path/text_file.txt',header=None,skiprows=1)
cols=pd.read_csv(r'path/text_file.txt',skipfooter=len(df)).columns
df[4]=df.loc[:,4:].agg(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()),1)
df=df.loc[:,:4]
df.columns=cols
df.to_csv(r'path/text_file.txt',index=False)
```

output of csv file after formatting:

```
col A,col B,col C,col D,col E
val A1,val B1,val C1,val D1,"val E1, val E2, val E3"
val A2,val B2, val C2,val D2, val E4
```